# How can i get date with time from DATE column in oracle database

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, hibernate

I dont know what i am doing wrong. When I try to get Date from database i get only date without time ;/

I map that column like that:

```
<property name="dataAktualizacji" type="date">
    <column name="DATA_AKTUALIZACJI" length="7" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

Comment: Try `timestamp` instead of `date`.

Comment: length = 7 might be a problem.

Comment: timestamp solved my problem :) thanks